# My brand new AT-2035 mic sounds EXTREMELY muffled. Can someone help me solve the problem?

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, audio, recording, sound

I have the mic hooked up to a Scarlett Solo and just as of recently my vocals are so muffled to how it sounded just a few months prior. I haven't recorded in a while and when I decided to start recording again, I ran into this problem. I thought something happened with the initial mic that I owned and I couldn't figure it out because maybe it was broken, so I just ordered a new one. But the same problem is happening. I tried changing the switches around on the mic itself. Tried moving the dials on the Scarlett and I even tested recording standing in different positions. But nothing seems to give. This a brand new mic too so the mic can't be the issue.

I am going to attach a link to the muffled audio sample that I uploaded to my google drive as well as an older audio sample that came out clearer. [Muffled Audio Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pFgwSwZNLySDgRlrfP2TUzj9eGJfoa3g/view?usp=sharing)     [Old Clearer Audio Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O--K3efWFlZjEQH0VMCveivUUAlxrltm/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It almost sounds like you're talking into the back of it - but assuming you're not, have you checked your full signal path right through from mic pre to DAW for such as a stray EQ patch? Is it still the same if you swap to a different mic entirely?

Comment: Yeah if I swap mics it's the same issue. I thought my old one was just busted from use but this is the same exact mic as the old one but brand new.

Answer (score 1):

My immediate thought was that you have the mic backwards. It is an extremely common mistake and this is a perfect description of what it sounds like when you have it backwards. If you are not sure there are a few ways to find out. One way would be to hold a flashlight up to the mic and look into the mesh of the mic itself and see if you can make out the diaphragm of the mic. It will be a big circular part that acts as the eardrum of the microphone. It’s really the only part inside your mic. Think of an ice cream cone. You would want the point of the cone pointed away from you and the bigger circle of the cone pointed at you. Also you can always do a test run and try recoding with it both ways and see if it makes a difference. I almost guarantee this is your problem. If that doesn’t fix it, try a different recording program. If you still are having the same problem, come back here and  post exact makes and models of your interface, your mic, the cord used to plug up the mic, the program or DAW you are using and computer make and model and current operating system (e Capitan, Big Sur?).

Good luck with your problem. Just be patient and focus on solutions and gaining knowledge. Every problem is an opportunity to learn something.

Comment: I tried both ways. I definitely am trying to record from the front of it and it's just odd because I recorded with the same set up for over a year and the only thing that changed is that I brought my set up from one place to another and got a sound shield mic stand instead of having it on a clamping stand clamped on my shelf in the closet. I thought maybe in the process of moving the mic to one place to another it stopped working properly so I ordered a new one of the same model and it's the same issue. I use audacity but I guess I just have to save up for pro tools to try to make it work.

Comment: But it just seems like it's a little crazy to think the DAW is the problem. But I flipped the mix testing the other direction it muffled even worse.